# Unable to add markers - only Location or Markers visible at once

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-maps-markers

I've a pretty large working app, I've implemented `myLocation` in `MapLocation.class` which extends Fragment.
Everything was working fine, my whole list of markers were displaying perfectly but after implementation of `myLocation`, a strange condition occurred.

Condition is on first run/install (after uninstalling the previous one or clearing the data), markers are displayed perfectly but neither `myLocation` works nor the `myLocation` icon appears, even it asks for permission.
On second run through studio or launching app again after clearing from recents, location works perfectly with the icon on its place but Markers become invisible. Invisible because camera focuses on Marker's place instead of `myLocation` as in the code.

Code is as follows:

```
public class MetroLocation extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    ArrayList<Double> arLat = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> arLong = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> arName=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> arLine = new ArrayList<>();
    double lng;
    double lat;
    LatLng latLng;
    Marker mCurrLocation;
    Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Cursor Lat;
    private Cursor Long;
    private Cursor Stations;
    private MyDatabase db;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_metro_location, container, false);
        mMapView = v.findViewById(R.id.mapLocation);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.onResume();
        db = new MyDatabase(getActivity());
        Lat = db.getLat();
        Long = db.getLong();
        Stations = db.getStation();
        Cursor line = db.getMetroLine();
        for(Lat.moveToFirst(); !Lat.isAfterLast(); Lat.moveToNext()) {
            arLat.add(Lat.getDouble(0));
        }
        for(Long.moveToFirst(); !Long.isAfterLast(); Long.moveToNext()) {
            arLong.add(Long.getDouble(0));
        }
        for(Stations.moveToFirst(); !Stations.isAfterLast(); Stations.moveToNext()) {
            arName.add(Stations.getString(0));
        }
        for(line.moveToFirst(); !line.isAfterLast(); line.moveToNext()) {
            arLine.add(line.getString(0));
        }
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Lat.close();
        Long.close();
        Stations.close();
        db.close();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocation != null) {
            mCurrLocation.remove();
        }
        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); 
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000); 
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(2F);
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            googleMap.clear();
            latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            mCurrLocation = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Connection Suspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Connection Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();
            } else {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {


                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
        googleMap = mMap;

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        for(int j= 0;j<arLat.size();j++) {
            double lat1 = arLat.get(j);
            double long1 = arLong.get(j);
            String name = arName.get(j);

            String snippet = "Metro Station"+ " Line : " + arLine.get(j);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat1, long1);

                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(name).snippet(snippet).flat(true).icon(
                        BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.green)));

        }
        int i = arLat.size() / 2;
        lat = arLat.get(i);
        lng = arLong.get(i);
        LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng1).zoom(12).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                buildGoogleApiClient();
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {

                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        if (mMapView != null &&
                mMapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")) != null) {
            View locationButton = mMapView.findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton");
            View locationButton1 = mMapView.findViewWithTag("GoogleMapCompass");
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 40, 253);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton1.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
            layoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,0);
            layoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            layoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            layoutParams1.bottomMargin = 100;
        }
    }
}
```

If there's something my code has wrong, please help.
**EDIT** - I've experienced that marker appears for a flash and then disappears. Everything else remains same. Also, a restart is required for location and it's button to appear.

Comment: No one is going to sift through that code or error log.  Instead, can you pare down your question to say the 5-10 lines of code where the problem is happening?  If you can't, then I'd say you should spend some time stepping through the code with a debugger to see if you can sniff out the problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can understand but the problem is logcat is not showing anything related to this problem so I've no clue where the code is failing. Removing logcat, useless.

Comment: I've worked pretty extensively with maps in Android, and the advice I would give you would be to revert to an earlier state where everything worked, then make _tiny_ incremental changes in the current direction.  When something starts to break, you may know the exact line which caused it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I got this feeling and tried the very same but it was not updating anything until I add those two `if`  in `onMapReady` and then everything happened suddenly.